# js function repeatedly invokes through an array of multipliers

Tags: javascript, multiplication, currying, partial-application

I am running into an error: `Uncaught TypeError TypeError: multipliers.reduce(...) is not a function`. I was looking at currying and partial application. I expected `multiply` function to correctly invoke through an array of multipliers. Can someone please explain what I'm missing in my `multiply` function?

multiply function that multiplies integers, but in a special way.
The function's output can be invoked repeatedly until you call it with no arguments.
For example, `multiply(3)(4)(5)()` should return `3 * 4 * 5 = 60`.
I am using a helper function `solution(multipliers)` that takes all the multipliers and then passes them to `multiply` as described above.

Input

```
multipliers: [3, 4, 5]
```

Output

```
60
```

Code

```
function multiply(x) {
    return function(y) { // anonymous function
        return function(z) { // anonymous function
            return x * y * z;
        }
    }
}

// this function lets you invoke something like multiply(3)(4)(5)() with dynamic arguments
function solution(multipliers) {
    return (multipliers.reduce((prev, arg) => {
        if (prev) {
            return prev(arg);
        }
        return multiply(arg);
    }, null))();
}

console.log(solution([3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: `multiply(3)(4)(5)` returns `3 * 4 + 5`. No extra `()` is necessary. No extra `solution` is necessary. You already curried the operation by declaring nested functions.

Comment: You cannot do currying with variadic (= taking arbitrary number of arguments) functions.  Don't try to mix them.

Comment: The idea is the input to be an array of multipliers. That is why I am using the `solution` function.

Comment: Your `multiply` function also performs addition, which is not what you described it to be. For example, you described that `multiply(2)(3)(5)()` should return `2 * 3 * 5 = 60`. However, your `multiply` function when applied as `multiply(2)(3)(5)` returns `2 * 3 + 5 = 17`. In addition, as you can see it doesn't take an arbitrary number of inputs. Instead, it always takes exactly 3 inputs. So, your question is inconsistent. Please elucidate what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated my implementation to `return x * y * z` to match the example.

Comment: You can look at this [Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153979/create-a-function-with-an-undetermined-number-of-successive-calls) if you are interested in a more general solution.

Comment: @imparante why are you calling `multipliers.reduce` as an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)? That's what's causing the error in the first place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to modify only the `multiply` function using currying thanks to @ghassen-louhaichi's link to a related question: [Create a function with an undetermined number of successive calls](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153979/create-a-function-with-an-undetermined-number-of-successive-calls).

```js
function multiply(x) {
    return function() {
        if (arguments.length == 0) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return multiply(x * arguments[0]);
        }
    }
}

// this function lets you invoke something like multiply(3)(4)(5)() with dynamic arguments
function solution(multipliers) {
    return (multipliers.reduce((prev, arg) => {
        if (prev) {
            return prev(arg);
        }
        return multiply(arg);
    }, null))();
}

console.log(solution([3, 4, 5]));
```

The first call to `multiply`, returns the inner function. depending on the number of arguments passed to the inner function, it returns the value of `multiply`'s argument as it is or it calls again ´multiply´ with the updated running total (thus returning again the inner function to be called again).

The limitation (of this implementation) is that you HAVE TO make a final call with no arguments to have to final value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to push all parameters to an array before calling an array method on it. Or else you can use the arguments parameters inside the function to get all the parameters.

Can you share how the function has been called?

Comment: Just edited the code example with the function call that I was using.

Comment: `console.log(solution([3, 4, 5]));`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `multiply` function as the initial value for the `reduce` call, and drop the final `()`:

```js
function solution(multipliers) {
    return multipliers.reduce((prev, arg) => prev(arg), multiply);
}
console.log(solution([3, 4, 5]));

function multiply(x) {
    return function(y) {
        return function(z) {
            return x * y + z;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I would like to maintain solution function as-is without changes and only update the `multiply function`.  The inner-most return is `return x * y * z`. I have just updated my implementation to match the example.

Comment: @imparante Sure you could replace `return x * y * z;` by `return function() { return x * y * z; };`, but really you should not. Your `solution` function is wrong and overly complicated, you should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your `multiply` function is defined incorrectly. If you want `multiply(3)(4)(5)()` to evaluate to `60` then you need to define the `multiply` function as follows.

```js
// x is required, y is optional, both are numbers
const getMultiply = (x) => (y) =>
  typeof y === "undefined" ? x : getMultiply(x * y);

// 1 is the identity element of multiplication
const multiply = getMultiply(1);

console.log(multiply(3)(4)(5)()); // 60
```

Once you define `multiply` correctly, you can define `solution` as follows.

```js
// x is required, y is optional, both are numbers
const getMultiply = (x) => (y) =>
  typeof y === "undefined" ? x : getMultiply(x * y);

// 1 is the identity element of multiplication
const multiply = getMultiply(1);

const solution = (multipliers) =>
  multipliers.reduce((f, x) => f(x), multiply)();

console.log(solution([3, 4, 5])); // 60
```

Comment: Thank you, I would like to maintain solution function as-is without changes and only update the `multiply function`

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the call to `multipliers.reduce(...)` as an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). This won't work because the result of calling the reduce in  your code is not a function, it's instead a number.

In the code you provided, you essentially wrote:

```js
function solution(multipliers) {
  return (60)(); // 60 here being the result of calling the reduce
}
```

Which explains the error you received.

All you need to do is omit the IIFE call. Your function becomes:

```js
function solution(multipliers) {
    return multipliers.reduce((prev, arg) => {
        if (prev) {
            return prev(arg);
        }
        return multiply(arg);
    }, null);
}
```

Finally, I suggest looking at some of the other answers here or in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153979/create-a-function-with-an-undetermined-number-of-successive-calls) for a better implementation of your `multiply` function to make it more generic.